# Flutter: Getting "Null check operator used on a null value" error creating MaterialColor

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm creating a custom `MaterialColor` object but it's throwing that error.

*colors.dart* (where I'm creating the `MaterialColor` object)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class JarsColors {
  static const MaterialColor palette = MaterialColor(
    0xFF276678,
    <int, Color> {
      0: Color(0xFFF6F5F5),
      100: Color(0xFFD3E0EA),
      400: Color(0xFF1687A7),
      500: Color(0xFF276678),
    }
  );
}
```

*main.dart*

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: JarsColors.palette,
      ),
      home: JarsHome(title: 'Hello'),
    );
  }
}
```

Error output:

```
The following _CastError was thrown building MyApp(dirty):
Null check operator used on a null value

The relevant error-causing widget was
MyApp
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      new ThemeData
#1      MyApp.build
#2      StatelessElement.build
#3      ComponentElement.performRebuild
#4      Element.rebuild
```

`flutter doctor` output

```
λ flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.928], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
[√] VS Code (version 1.55.2)
[√] Connected device (3 available)

• No issues found!
```

Comment: JarsColors.palette look null from error, can you print to see if outputs anything

Comment: @flakerimi it outputs `I/flutter ( 6706): MaterialColor(primary value: Color(0xff276678))
`

Answer (score 2):

I managed to make it work by adding more shades to the `MaterialColor` `swatch` argument:

```
class JarsColors {
  static const MaterialColor palette = MaterialColor(
    0xFF276678,
    <int, Color> {
      50: Color(0xFFF6F5F5),
      100: Color(0xFFD3E0EA),
      200: Color(0xFFD3E0EA),
      300: Color(0xFFD3E0EA),
      400: Color(0xFF1687A7),
      500: Color(0xFF276678),
      600: Color(0xFFD3E0EA),
      700: Color(0xFF1687A7),
    }
  );
}
```

With the help of: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialColor-class.html

Nonetheless I can't find an explanation to this. It'd be great to know.

Answer (score 1):

To keep answer short and straight forward, when defining MaterialColor you must start from 50, then 100 and increments in interval of 100 to 800 is enough to allow you to use it without null check errors, check this one how they did it here

[How to define and use custom MaterialColor in flutter](https://medium.com/py-bits/turn-any-color-to-material-color-for-flutter-d8e8e037a837)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation of `MaterialColor` class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialColor-class.html):

> Defines a single color as well a color swatch with **ten** shades of the color.
>
> The color's shades are referred to by index. The greater the index, the darker the color. There are *10 valid indices: **50, 100, 200, ..., 900***. The value of this color should the same the value of index 500 and shade500.

So, this error is not prompted only when the following two conditions are satisfied:

1. There should be ten items on the list.
2. The items should be indexed as 50,100,200, ..., 900.
   Missing any of these two above points will cause the aforesaid error.
   We can fill in some dummy colours in order to make a list of 10.

Thus, we can correct your `colors.dart` file as follows:

```
class JarsColors {
  static const MaterialColor palette = MaterialColor(
    0xFF276678,
    <int, Color> {
      0: Color(0xFFF6F5F5),
      100: Color(0xFFD3E0EA),
      200: Color(0x235C6C),
      300: Color(0xFF6894A1),
      400: Color(0xFF1687A7),
      500: Color(0xFF276678),
      600: Color(0xFFFFFFFF), //white (no relation with specified shade)
      700: Color(0xFF000000), //black (no relation with specified shade)
      800: Color(0xFFA1A1A1), //random (no relation with specified shade)
      900: Color(0xFF2A2A2A), //random (no relation with specified shade)
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by, *”…is not prompted only when…”*?